# How to distinguish the sent or received in the same folder?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have two questions when using the java-mail library.
1. When I am using the java-mail to receive the emails from this emailbox through ima protocol, is there any way to distinguish which one is sent out, and which one is received? Like below scenario:

I send an email to myself, like from `ydcrm@foxmail.com` to `ydcrm@foxmail.com`, so by default, there are 2 emails generated, one is in inbox, and the other is in sent(outbox). After that, I moved those 2 emails to the same folder like `private`. When processing these 2 emails, I found the header information of that 2 message are exactly the same. Is there a way to get the source folder(inbox or outbox) when parsing a message?

> X-QQ-FEAT:
>   YqUsWGMTFZakOmi/23pXThZvucY/N6XbIJhTWnLiS4PItC6RG3SaGEuD8zzkV\r\n\tD+8wZrA6lbHgKPY5QyFRtqlfI/UT7wWSQeop5ujBkhex04Tv5iXQi0w76Bg4D+YKcNT/jL7\r\n\tCa7u5VY9X+WNDBm0Y1KqML4z10z7mojOyl2sZlspMacMCektMRet8K5zRsgDuv9fTnVP5hQ\r\n\tTuppdT0Wo/UmWwdQN3mhRiGrfEWXsfx4=","X-QQ-SSF:
>   0001000000000010000000000000001","X-HAS-ATTACH:
>   no","X-QQ-BUSINESS-ORIGIN: 2","X-Originating-IP:
>   180.171.94.161","X-QQ-STYLE: ","X-QQ-mid: webmail581t1551627212t283464","From: \"=?gb18030?B?Sm9l?=\"
>   ","To: \"=?gb18030?B?eWRjcm0=?=\"
>   ","Subject:
>   =?gb18030?B?t6K4+NfUvLo=?=","Mime-Version: 1.0","Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\r\n\tboundary=\"----=_NextPart_5C7BF3CC_0AC4EFC0_606CED18\"","Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit","Date: Sun, 3 Mar 2019 23:33:32 +0800","X-Priority:
>   3","Message-ID:
>   ","X-QQ-MIME:
>   TCMime 1.0 by Tencent","X-Mailer: QQMail 2.x","X-QQ-Mailer: QQMail
>   2.x"]

2. Is there any way to get the "Default Sender Account" information by the library? 
   [Screenshot of emailbox account setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWHxB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find that the received message has "Received" headers that the sent message does not.  There may be other headers that exist only on the received message.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, but the "Received" header is null. I tried to get hte "Received" header like this : log.info("Received: {} - {}", message.getHeader("Received"), message.getHeader("received"));

Comment: Compare all the headers of the sent vs. received messages and see if you can find other differences in the headers.